# How to call an object created by a function, that is now in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, javascript-objects

This is my fist question on here, so be nice :D

I am building a basic texting web app and I'm totally stuck. I have a function that creates an object with "name" and "number" values, for a new contact.  That object is then pushed into my "contact" array. It all looks like this:

```
var contacts = [];
$("#add-contact").click(function () {
    var newName = $("#new-name").val();
    function contactName(name, number) {
        this.name = name;
        this.number = number;
    }
    var newNumber = $("#new-number").val();
    var newPerson = new contactName(newName, newNumber);
    contacts.push(newPerson);
    console.log(contacts)
```

I then should be able to use that information and then enter in a contact name, have a function search my "contacts" array, give me the index and then use the index to call the name and number so I can then send a message and have it all displayed right (not shown). My calling funtion looks like this:

```
$("#send-button").click(function () {
    var userNumber = $("#number-input").val();
    var userIndexNumber = contacts.indexOf(userNumber);
    appendToConvo(contacts[userIndexNumber]);
    });
```

The "appendToConvo" was just so I could see if I was outputting the right information.

When I ran the first function in Chrome, the console showed that my "contacts" array contained only [contactname]. The function is adding the data for name and number, just not the name of the object to the array, I think. Chrome displays this:
[Chrome console message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZrs8.png)
This has been driving me crazy for a little bit and I just need some help! Thanks to anyone that can help me!!!

Comment: So what's the problem? Everything seems in order. The console message shows that there's 3 contacts. What do you see if you replace `appendToConvo` with `console.log`?

Comment: I don't fully understand what do you want to achieve and what's the exact problem. But I do see one thing: if you want to find a contact by number, you cannot use indexOf like that. You have to iterate through the array and check if the number provided is the sane as the item.number. If so, you can return that object as a search result.

Comment: You definitely should move that `contactName` constructor function out of the click handler. And camelcase the name!

Answer (score 1):

contacts is an array of contactName objects, not an array of numbers, so `contacts.indexOf(userNumber)` is returning -1 (indexOf uses strict equality to compare elements against the passed argument, and none of the objects in your array is strictly equal to `userNumber`). I suggest you use something like the following to find the contact you are interest in finding:

```
var matchingContacts = $.grep(contacts, function (c) {
  return c.number === user.number;
});
appendToConvo(matchingContacts[0]);
```